# Obtaining 4-4.2V rail from 5V output of LM7805 voltage regulator

Tags: power-supply, shift-register, 5v, tube

I'm creating a numitron clock with 4xIV-9 tubes (seven-segment filament displays) and have decided to illuminate them using shift registers controlled by an arduino. Each segment takes a voltage of 4-4.2V and around 17-20mA of current.

My voltage I have available is a 5V output voltage from an LM7805 voltage regulator IC. I need to power 4 high current shift registers (TPIC6B595), each with an expected maximum output current of 200mA. Owing to this, the 4-4.2V rail needs to be able to handle a maximum current draw of around 800mA. 
I was considering using a simple potential divider however calculated that the required power losses greatly exceed that of the standard resistors that I have available.
I was also considering using a diode to drop the voltage however the forward voltage is a function of the current; therefore as the current can vary from the extremes of 0mA to 800mA I did not think a diode would be appropriate.

Any suggestions on how to obtain 4-4.2ish V rail would be much appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: Add a Schottky and a normal diode in series? Perhaps two Schottkys.

Comment: Where does the 200 mA to be sinked by the TPIC6B595's come from? Is it related to the IV-9 tubes? TPIC6B595 is an open drain device and the high current outputs will only sink current to ground, but not source current. Because of this, if the devices driven by TPIC6B595's are sourcing their current from a higher voltage rail, that current will never pass through the LM7805 and can be omitted from its current budget.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace the 7805 with a 1Amp or more adjustable regulator and set it to 4.2 volts. Run both the arduino and everything from that  instead of running it off the 5V. The Arduino will be fine with 4.2 volts without any issue, and it makes it easier since you dont have to worry about level translation for the input lines either.

Answer (score 4):

The Atmega microcontroller in the Arduino will run fine at 4V, so the simplest solution would be to power the whole thing from a 4-4.2V switching power supply instead of using a voltage regulator.

Since 4.2V is the end of charge voltage of LiIon cells, there are plenty of off the shelf [4.2V power supplies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07S21YNRG) available.

Failing that, you can use a SMPS or wall wart with adjustable voltage, or simply change the feedback resistor in a 5V 1-2 Amps USB "phone charger" to make it output 4.2V instead of 5V.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that the input voltage that feeds the 7805 regulator is significantly higher than 5V.  If so, I would use a small adjustable SMPS Buck Regulator that operates from that input supply.

You can either build one yourself or simply purchase one of the very inexpensive boards / modules from your favourite supplier.

Set the output voltage to the desired value.

The advantage of this approach is that you are not dissipating all that power in the 7805 regulator.

Comment: Indeed.  It's important to realize that a linear voltage regulator is just a resisitive divider with a self-adjuster circuit to handle variation in load.  Even in the ideal case passing close to an amp across just the dropout voltage is going to waste about a third of the total power consumption as heat, so a switcher is far preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Use an adjustable voltage regulator.

Answer (score 1):

Use a low-dropout adjustable voltage regulator. Measure the output voltage of the 7805 and make sure you are really getting at least 5V, then look for a regulator that will work with an input-output voltage difference of, say, 0.5V or less.

Comment: Not a very good idea.  Makes far more sense to run the adjustable regulator off the same source as the 7805, or instead of the 7805... but really this is a task for a switcher.